# wsimport unable to parse XSD - path encoding issue?

Tags: java, maven, wsdl, wsimport

I am developing a web service through jaxws and Java. I have a WSDL that imports an XSD, here's a fragment from my WSDL. As you can see, it's pretty standard.

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://blah.com">
<xsd:import schemaLocation="../xsd/myschema.xsd" namespace="http://blah.com"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

I am using a Maven plugin to generate my types using wsimport.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.12</version>
<configuration>
<wsdlDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
<packageName>com.blah.service.generated</packageName>
<keep>true</keep>
<sourceDestDir>${basedir}/target/generated/src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
</configuration>
<executions>
<execution>
<goals>
<goal>wsimport</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Everything worked fine when I build locally (Windows), everything worked fine in an environment we were using (Linux). However, we've now moved to an new environment and are seeing the following error.

```
[ERROR] Unable to parse "file:/xsd/myschema.xsd" : Illegal character in path at index 84: file:/apps/buildeng/workspace/workspace/Blah/Blah/Business%20Blah{PR102483}/BLAGHASFASD/BLALALALALALALAL-Web-Service-Build/src/main/wsdl/mywsdl.wsdl
  line 13 of file:/apps/buildeng/workspace/workspace/Blah/Blah/Business%20Blah{PR102483}/BLAGHASFASD/BLALALALALALALAL-Web-Service-Build/src/main/wsdl/mywsdl.wsdl

[ERROR] com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; systemId: file:/apps/buildeng/workspace/workspace/Blah/Blah/Business%20Blah{PR102483}/BLAGHASFASD/BLALALALALALALAL-Web-Service-Build/src/main/wsdl/mywsdl.wsdl; lineNumber: 13; columnNumber: 89; Unable to parse "file:/xsd/myschema.xsd" : Illegal character in path at index 84: file:/apps/buildeng/workspace/workspace/Blah/Blah/Business%20Blah{PR102483}/BLAGHASFASD/BLALALALALALALAL-Web-Service-Build/src/main/wsdl/mywsdl.wsdl
  line 9 of file:/apps/buildeng/workspace/workspace/Blah/Blah/Business%20Blah{PR102483}/BLAGHASFASD/BLALALALALALALAL-Web-Service-Build/src/main/wsdl/mywsdl.wsdl
```

I've mangled my path a little to take out some of the important words. The path on this new environment is considerably longer then previously, and now contains curly brace characters {} - could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is for sure. unfortunately wsimport is not encoding your curly braces simbols (%7B for { and %7D for } ).

I guess it's a bug. The path should look like /apps/buildeng/workspace/workspace/Blah/Blah/Business%20Blah%7BPR102483%7D/BLAGHASFASD/BLALALALALALALAL-Web-Service-Build/src/main/wsdl/mywsdl.wsdl

Can you try to use global path instead of relative to check if this is the problem?